# Display image in full page with transparent background in web

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the image on click like it displays in http://www.espncricinfo.com/ at this website when you click on the image it opens in same full window with transparent background.
how i can do this.i'm developing a php website.
Thanks

Comment: Look up Fancybox and the like.

Comment: Or try lightbox variants.  [Example](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) :)

Comment: http://www.designresourcebox.com/a-collection-of-useful-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes-31-plugins/

Comment: thank you so much Jan Dvorak,c24w,Alex,pylover.your answers helped me a lot.thanks again :) especially c24w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like using [ColorBox,](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) it's done everything I've needed to with pictures plus can do page  with iframes. I've never looked at fancy box but have heard it is very similar.

[Examples](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)

Is triggered by `$('Selector').colorbox({Options});`

Comment: your post was also helpful.but i'd use light box which was suggested by c24w